# O que é linguagem de programação concatenativa?

Tags: característica-linguagem, paradigma-de-programação

Não consegui entender a definição feita pelo Wikipédia.

> Linguagem de programação concatenativa é uma linguagem de programação na qual todas as construções válidas, ou termos, correspondem a uma função e a sobreposição de termos denota composição de função.
>
> A combinação de uma semântica de composição com uma sintaxe que a reflete faz as linguagens concatenativas bastante adequadas para manipulação algébrica e análise formal, defendem alguns pesquisadores.

Qual a sintaxe disso?

Existe alguma linguagem de programação atual que entra nesse tipo de linguagem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Segundo a Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenative_programming_language), exemplos de linguagens concatenativas são Cat, Enchilada, Factor, Onyx, PostScript, RPL, Staapl, Trith, XY, Kitten, Om, Min e Forth portanto nenhuma usada de fato por alguém hoje em dia, e isto por si só indica que não deva perder muito tempo com este paradigma. PostScript é a mais conhecida (RPL já foi usada minimamente no passado) e ela é usada para um nicho muito específico (impressão) e na prática as pessoas não programam nela manualmente. Forth é interessante e já foi bastante usada até para fazer alguns jogos de vídeo quando havia muito pouca memória e capacidade de processamento. Ela é simples como Assembly, mas poderosa e mais fácil

Uma das vantagens desse tipo de sintaxe é a redução de código, porque você escreve só o que precisa fazer com o dado. A expressão do código se dá de forma menos imperativa, como é o normal das linguagens que conhecemos, ela é mais declarativa, mas com sintaxe simplificada. Ela costuma ser baseada em pilha de dados, como costuma ser o computador em certo nível, então a execução se dá em cima de dados que estão na pilha de dados, por isso você tem uma operação que empilha os dados e operações que executam algo neles. Ainda que diferente se parece com a execução baseada em registradores, mais típico de como o computador funciona na sua base, mas é ainda mais simples, porque com registradores é preciso dizer quais estão envolvidos, com pilha, são sempre os que estão no topo da pilha, nem precisa dizer quais são.

Por isso você pode só dizer o que fazer sem se preocupar com o que fará, será sempre o tipo da pilha, dão vem o nome do paradigma, você vai colocando uma execução atrás da outra concatenando as operações em cima dos mesmos dados ou os que se derivam desses dados iniciais. Para quem conhece programação funcional, é como criar um *pipe* de execução. Em C# e linguagem que copiaram o LINQ é parecido, você diz o que quer em cima do mesmo dado. LINQ isoladamente é praticamente uma linguagem concatenativa.

Ela dá uma simplificação enorme sobre o estado que está manipulando, mas também complica com construções onde tem muitos estados, e onde tem muitas vertentes de execução. Ela funciona bem quando pega alguns poucos dados e eles vão sendo manipulados em sequência até chegar no resultado final. Por isso é muito mais fácil escrever códigos para ela, e mais fácil ainda achar *bugs*, desde que esteja usando onde ela é adequada.

Em geral essas linguagens são [homoicônicas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity) e usam [*monoids*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid). E costuma ser fácil escrever compiladores para elas, ainda que isso pode ser até um ponto negativo para o resultado geral.

Não entendeu nada? Não tem problema, não ajuda a maioria dos programadores saber disso. Até ajuda, mas é preciso construir o conhecimento todo para se chegar aí. Este é um tijolo solto, precisam de outros embaixo dele para que este conhecimento forme uma parede sólida.

Sintaxe de PS:

```
%!PS
 /Courier             % name the desired font
 20 selectfont        % choose the size in points and establish 
                      % the font as the current one
 72 500 moveto        % position the current point at 
                      % coordinates 72, 500 (the origin is at the 
                      % lower-left corner of the page)
 (Hello world!) show  % stroke the text in parentheses
 showpage             % print all on the page
```

E de RPL:

```
0       @ Start with zero on the stack
1 10    @ Loop from 1 to 10
FOR I   @ "I" is the local variable
   I +  @ Add "I" to the running total
NEXT    @ Repeat...
```

E Forth:

```
0 value ii        0 value jj
0 value KeyAddr   0 value KeyLen
create SArray   256 allot   \ state array of 256 bytes
: KeyArray      KeyLen mod   KeyAddr ;

: get_byte      + c@ ;
: set_byte      + c! ;
: as_byte       255 and ;
: reset_ij      0 TO ii   0 TO jj ;
: i_update      1 +   as_byte TO ii ;
: j_update      ii SArray get_byte +   as_byte TO jj ;
: swap_s_ij
    jj SArray get_byte
       ii SArray get_byte  jj SArray set_byte
    ii SArray set_byte
;

: rc4_init ( KeyAddr KeyLen -- )
    256 min TO KeyLen   TO KeyAddr
    256 0 DO   i i SArray set_byte   LOOP
    reset_ij
    BEGIN
        ii KeyArray get_byte   jj +  j_update
        swap_s_ij
        ii 255 < WHILE
        ii i_update
    REPEAT
    reset_ij
;
: rc4_byte
    ii i_update   jj j_update
    swap_s_ij
    ii SArray get_byte   jj SArray get_byte +   as_byte SArray get_byte  xor
;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Portugol/ExampleForth.fth).

Comment: Bom saber que não preciso me atualizar com isso. Apenas entender o conceito parece suficiente.

Comment: Maniero, quando você vem pra Piracicaba dar uma palestra sobre Microsoft LUIS?

Comment: Nunca! Eu não piso em Piracicaba... :D Mentira, eu costumo ir sempre, estudei aí. Mas o "nunca" é que eu não mexo com LUIS e não pretendo mexer, por isso nunca palestrarei sobre isso em Piracicaba ou outro lugar. Mas se tiver organizado algum evento legal que vá bastante gente eu posso trazer alguém que manja bem disso.

Comment: Puxa, do jeito que você fala do assunto parece que o negócio ainda precisa amadurecer bastante. Estou usando o QnA Maker para um chatbot de FAQ. Até que é bom. Teve o DevPira esses dias. Mas eu não fui.

Comment: Também precisa, não vejo resultados reais bons, por isso tem gente usando como marketing positivo que atendem com seres humanos.